# How to customise the alertdialog in Android?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` in my application, for which I want to have a background for the whole `dialog`, and a background and text color for the 2 buttons. I cannot seem to customise the alertDialog. How can I do it? I want the dialog to look like the image below.

[image]

Comment: Look into `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`

Comment: @BenP. thanks,i checked that out, and that solved my problem!

Comment: @ADM I used `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` as suggested by Ben above

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, basic step are:

- Create your custom layout
- Create dialog builder and set the custom view. (builder.setView(your_custom_view))

There are a ton of tutorials out there, even here in SOF. Please do a search first.

https://suragch.medium.com/creating-a-custom-alertdialog-bae919d2efa5
https://www.journaldev.com/22153/android-custom-alert-dialog

Answer (score 1):

First, create your layout.xml for the dialog, and then for the example codes to call your dialog is like

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.AlertDialog);
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
builder.setView(view);
final androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
if (alertDialog.getWindow() != null) {
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
}
alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
alertDialog.show();
```

and if you want to declare your view inside your **layout.xml**

```
TextView txexample = view.findViewById(R.id.txexample);
```